# How to compare 2 dataframes in python unittest using assert methods

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, python-unittest, assert

I'm writing unittest for a method that returns a dataframe, but, while testing the output using:

`self.asserEquals(mock_df, result)`

I'm getting ValueError:

`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Right now I'm comparing properties that serves the purpose now,

```
self.assertEqual(mock_df.size, result.size)
self.assertEqual(mock_df.col_a.to_list(), result.col_a.to_list())
self.assertEqual(mock_df.col_b.to_list(), result.col_b.to_list())
self.assertEqual(mock_df.col_c.to_list(), result.col_c.to_list())
```

but curious how do I assert dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd

class TestDataFrame(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dataframe(self):
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3.0, 4.0]})
        self.assertEqual(True, df1.equals(df2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks, Mahi, though it's working in some cases. For a few I get `AssertionError` visually the data looks the same and is indexed properly.

Comment: I also had an issue with this approach not working.  I found an alternate approach that worked and posted that as an alternate answer.

Comment: I think you can simplify slightly using self.assertTrue(df1.equals(df2))

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer from @Mahi did not work for me.  It failed for two Dataframes that should have been equal.  Not sure why.

As I discovered [here](https://mungingdata.com/pandas/unit-testing-pandas/) under "DataFrame equality", there are some functions built into Pandas for testing.

The following worked for me. I tested it several times, but not exhaustively, to make sure it would work repeatedly.

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd

class test_something(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method(self):
        #... create dataframes df1 and df2...
        pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1,df2)
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) is related pandas reference for the above function.

Comment: assert_frame_equal is good for testing. If the test fails, it also shows the differences between the two dataframes.